# Cannot deploy Docker Swarm stack in rootless mode, mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've set up Docker in rootless mode under Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11 (in my case, using Ansible and [this role](https://github.com/konstruktoid/ansible-docker-rootless)). I want to deploy a simple Docker stack to the node via Docker Swarm. No other hosts are involved, just one Swarm node from the same machine, acting as a manager.

I can run this project with Docker and Docker Compose just fine, also in rootless mode. All that changes for the rootless setup is that `DOCKER_HOST` is overwritten in `.bashrc`:

```sh
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock"
```

When I deploy the stack though, none of the services can start (here is an excerpt of the status):

```sh
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml demo-stack
$ docker stack ps demo-stack --no-trunc
jig6zyewkem2g225509x91nt5   demo-stack_db.1                  registry.example.com/db:v1.20.2      bullseye   Shutdown        Rejected 15 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied"   
ox6x5w7du9o5ew2v70g5mfg9e   demo-stack_redis.1               registry.example.com/redis:v1.20.2   bullseye   Shutdown        Rejected 15 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied"   
ipme447wrrsjc8jw6cpfak4hq   demo-stack_web.1                 registry.example.com/web:v1.20.2     bullseye   Shutdown        Rejected 14 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied"
```

The services all error with `mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied`. I suppose that it tries to start them as if the system was using rootful Docker, but it's a rootless installation.

I guess the question is: how do I get the Swarm node (which is the very same machine) to use the correct Docker rootless configuration for launching the services? That would include using the correct `DOCKER_HOST` configuration.

I am unsure if this is even supposed to work. I hear that overlay networks are not supported, but I am only on one machine, so I don't really need this. I *do* need Swarm for its usable implementation of secrets (compared to the mock implementation from Docker Compose).

Note that I have the same setup with Docker running in (normal) rootful mode, and there, all services can be started. It's therefore *not* an issue with the Docker stack file itself.

More details with `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 12
 Server Version: 20.10.13
 Storage Driver: fuse-overlayfs
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: hpzsmez48acse9yo1frnx37fo
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: zkv7wsoun193kyvbxe1k3hdph
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 127.0.0.1
  Manager Addresses:
   127.0.0.1:2377
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2a1d4dbdb2a1030dc5b01e96fb110a9d9f150ecc
 runc version: v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  rootless
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.0-13-amd64
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.936GiB
 Name: bullseye
 ID: 3R5P:2UV6:FIP4:UIJV:TDNQ:35DT:DEDI:SMGN:FDUY:JSWO:FRU6:O2HF
 Docker Root Dir: /home/vagrant/.local/share/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
WARNING: No io.weight support
WARNING: No io.weight (per device) support
WARNING: No io.max (rbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (wbps) support
WARNING: No io.max (riops) support
WARNING: No io.max (wiops) support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple: Docker Rootless does not work with Docker Swarm. You can have either, but not both.